# What can I do with this psd stencil for Android?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am a software developer and need to make some mockups for an application (and not very familiar with Photoshop). I downloaded the .psd file from http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html but am unsure how to use them. From what I can tell there is no easy way besides copying and pasting things together. Is there a better way? I've Googled around quite a bit but only find MORE psd files. HOW can I easily mockup some screens using these psd files?

Comment: Yes, they are pretty much designed for copying and pasting elements together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to do visual mockups and you have never used it, perhaps Photoshop is not the right way to go. You can do anything with it, it's an amazing tool, but there are other ones that have been thought specially for designing wireframes.

My favourite one is [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups). It's free, super easy to install and use, and the results are great. If you don't like this one, there are plenty of others, just do a search for mockup tools (some stack sites like https://ux.stackexchange.com/ use Balsamiq for posting mockups straight from the soft to a question/answer).

[image]

[image]